# How to do one sample t.test() when log transformed for normality in R?

Tags: r, statistics

The dataframe df has single numeric column called ReviewLength

The test is whether review lengths are greater than their mean value (assume 456)

Non-transformed t.test would be:

```
t.test(df$ReviewLength, mu=456, alternative="greater")
```

For transformed, I am assuming something like this

```
log_ReviewLength <- log(df$ReviewLength)
log_mean <- log_ReviewLength([,1])
t.test(log_ReviewLength, mu=log_mean, alternative="greater")
```

Questions

1. Is this logic even correct use of `t.test` when values were transformed?
2. No matter how I try, I end up with `-Inf` when trying to get the mean of the log values.  I have searched high and low on what can be causing it, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: `log(0)` is `-Inf`. And if it is included in a mean, the mean will be `-Inf` too.

Comment: `log_ReviewLength([,1])` is not valid R code: 1) `log_ReviewLength` is a vector, not a function; 2) and it's not a table with rows and columns, `[, 1]` is wrong.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!